# Counting info in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a problem, am trying to count all notice's for people i have in same row table friends

its like counting all notice which you must see

but am getting this error

:mysql::st execute failed: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
TABLE  notice

id  user  info
1   0771  tes
2   0881  coma
3   0555  tue

TABLE friends

id  acc    friend
1   0771   0881
2   0881   0555
3
```

QUERY

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM notice 
WHERE user IN (SELECT acc, friend 
               FROM friends 
               WHERE acc = '0771' 
                  OR friend = '0771')
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: `WHERE user IN`. 1 column. `SELECT acc, friend`. 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM notice 
JOIN friends ON notice.user IN (friends.acc, friends.friend) 
WHERE '0771' IN (friends.acc, friends.friend)
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs to be selecting a single value, you have it selecting both `acc` and `friend` when it needs to only be selecting whatever the correct column is for identifying the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `notice` 
WHERE `user` IN (SELECT `acc` 
               FROM `friends` 
               WHERE `friend` = '0771')
OR `user` = '0771'
```

The error you are getting: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` is because you select both `acc` and `friends` in your subquery.